# kotlin / java sharedPreferences meaning in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What exactly does the sharedPreferences built in function mean in Kotlin / android studio? I've tried reading the documentation from the official android studio docs and would like a simple understanding on how I can use to share the data.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences in Kotlin/Java can be used to store data values of type (String, Int, Long, Float, Boolean etc) in the system's memory, so that even after the application terminates so that you can retrieve it later on.

Let's say you want save a String value,

```
// Declare a shared preference
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences('MySharedPref', MODE_PRIVATE)

// Initial value
val doorState: String = "Opened"

editDoorState(doorState)
// So whenever the doorState changes, we can save it, so even if the application is
// terminated or killed and restarts again, the last edited value can be retrieved.
// This is commonly used to store a single data value.



// Function to save the doorstate change(of type String) 
fun editDoorState(value: String) {
  val sharedPrefEditor = sharedPref.edit()

  // Where the 'doorState' is the SharedPreference Key.
  // To retrieve the value, key must be produced.
  sharedPrefEditor.putString('doorState', value)
  sharedPrefEditor.commit()
}
```

For more information, check out the official documentation from Android [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).